# Loop aquery through multiple Databases

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have up to 5 databases , all with same the Tables.
I'm trying to run through the same Query through all databases.

What is the best way of doing so.

Code i tried:

`$system_list = $dbcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM db_list WHERE active='1'");
 $system_list->execute();
 while ($system_list_data = $system_list->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){`

```
$mac_search_fetch = $system_list_data['db_connect']->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mac = :mac");
$mac_search_fetch->bindParam(':mac', $mac_int, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$mac_search_fetch->execute();`

}
```

Fatal Error: Call to a member function prepare() on string.

ALL Databases are defined in my db.class